# Chrome fonts weird rendering

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

My google chrome browser started behaving strangely concerning fonts rendering under Ubuntu 16.04:

[image]

[image]

It started happening today only in chrome. Firefox is all good.
It appears that anti-aliasing settings in unity-tweak-tool doesn't have any effect in the referred problem. Just tried all of them with no avail.

Is anyone having the same issue?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked your font settings within Chrome?  `Settings > Advanced Settings > Web Content > Customize fonts`.  I would recommend trying to set them back to defaults first.  Let me know if that does anything.

Comment: Type **chrome://settings/fonts** in chrome address bar to open fonts settings. See if any font was configured in bold type.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since a couple days ago. Running Linux Mint (the one based on Ubuntu 16.04). I just reset all my fonts and nothing.

Comment: @Budius Another thing to look for would be updates for Chrome itself.  I have seen a number of questions today regarding Linux and Chrome that seem to have been fixed by updates.

Comment: @CheesusCrust, i coudn't find this path of settings in chrome. It appears that all chrome settings are accessible only through `chrome://settings`.

Comment: I was leading through the UI without pictures, hah.  The link @Biswa gave you should send you to the same place I was trying to.

Comment: @CheesusCrust, ok, i have:`standard font:` Times New Roman; `serif font:` Times New Roman; `sans-serif font:` Arial; `fixed width font:` monospace. None in bold type.
Just tried `apt-get update/upgrade`, reinstalled chrome in synaptic but still same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved by "Resetting all to default" in `chrome://flags` and restarting the browser. Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2):

I found the culprit. I had the "GPU Rasterization" Chrome Flag (chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization) set to "Force-enabled for all layers". Changing that back to "Default" and restarting Chrome fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I my case reset all flags was not enough. '#enable-gpu-rasterization' has to be set to Disabled to fix Fonts rendering issue. The default option is not always is 'Disabled'.